# Sed and awk causing line wrap-around

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I have a file of the form:

```
FA01_01:The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks  
FA01_02:Glue the sheet to the dark blue background
```

I need it to be of the form (also note the use of lowercase):

```
<s> the birch canoe slid on the smooth planks </s> (FA01_01)  
<s> glue the sheet to the dark blue background </s> (FA01_02)
```

so I tried the following expression with sed:

```
sed 's/\(.......\):\(.*$\)/(\1) <s> \2 <\/s>/' tmp.dat
```

but this is what it returned:

```
</s> (FA01_01)anoe slid on the smooth planks  
</s> (FA01_02)eet to the dark blue background
```

For whatever reason, it appears that sed is causing the replaced pattern to wrap around to the beginning of the line but only for the second match. Example:

```
$> sed 's/\(.......\):\(.*$\)/\1 \2/' tmp.dat
FA01_01 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks
```

Is correct, but

```
$>sed 's/\(.......\):\(.*$\)/\2 \1/' tmp.dat
FA01_01h canoe slid on the smooth planks
```

This even occurs with awk as well. For sake of testing the wraparound hypothesis:

```
$> awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print tolower($2) "XXX"}' tmp.dat
XXX birch canoe slid on the smooth planks
```

but

```
$> awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print tolower($1) "XXX"}' tmp.dat
fa01_01XXX
```

Any ideas what would be causing this line wrap? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the second pattern or saved column goes until the end of line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that your tmp.dat is probably in DOS format (with \r characters). You could try to convert it to linux format (with only \n), for example with the command:

```
dos2unix tmp.dat
```

And then execute:

```
sed 's/\(.......\):\(.*$\)/<s>\L \2 \E<\/s> (\1)/' tmp.dat
```

Comment: I didn't find a dos2unix program, so I did a `tr -d '\r'` to a temporary file. And you're right. I did some temporary tests and the '\r' character will put what follows to the beginning of the current line. Thanks.